# How transaction isolation level changes the whole transaction using several @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

```
@Transactional
public void a() {
  b();
  c();
}

@Transactonal(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void b() {
  // some code with update in db
}

public void c() {
  // some code with selects and updates in db
}
```

What isolation level will be used in method 'c'?
As far as I understand, it all will be a one transaction. And in method 'b' we just join to current transaction and change its isolation level. But will it be changed back to default after method b execution?

I ask it because in such situation on big load we got 'PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update' in method 'c', although i want to have a default isolation level in method 'c'.

Comment: isolation level won;t change the annotations on both `b` and `c` are ignored. Unless that method is on another object instead of an internal method call (and than the code doesn't match your reality).